# ERROR in downloading paperclip attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, rails-models

I have a model named VehiclePhotos and it has attachment field 'photo'. I used paperclip gem for uploading photos. Uploading was fine without any error. but when I tried to download the image, it gives

> '500 Internal Server Error'.

log does not shows any error details.

**vehicle_photos.rb**

```
class VehiclePhotos < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo,
                    :url => "/uploads/:class/:id/:attachment/:attachment_fullname?:timestamp",
                    :path => "uploads/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:basename.:extension"
end
```

in view, given following code to download

```
<%= link_to @object.photo_file_name , @object.photo.url %>
```

The file which contains uploaded photos has name 'vehicle_photos' and it has permission 777.

Comment: add some more error code, to find the cause of the error.

Comment: in browser it shows 'sorry, something went wrong' and in network tab shows '500 Internal Server Error' . only this much is showing..

Answer (score 0):

"sorry, something went wrong" message usually does not show up in development environment. Instead, you would see a detailed error message with backtrace etc. So maybe you're running in production env? Then your error would go to production.log - check there. You couldn't guess the cause of error without the error details

Comment: in production log also not showing any error details.. so I dont have any idea of debugging this error..

Comment: if you're running your app via passenger on nginx or apache as a proxy, check their logs too, passenger could log some critical errors there, so they wouldn't arrive in local app logs at all